# orange pi pc armbian ssh недоступен при отсутствии подключения клиента спустя определенное время

Tags: linux, ssh

Спустя время если клиент не подключен к серверу, невозможно подключится по `ssh` , `apache`  и `smtp` не работают, тоесть все сервисы отключаются. как застаить сервер быть все время доступным? может что подправить в `sshd.config`?

Физически отключаю сервер от розетки и потом включаю, все работает некое время потом доступ недоступен. пока по ssh клиент все время подключен все нормально.

Стоит отключится на время процедуру приходится выполнять заново и запускать все сервисы: монтировать жесткий диск и запускать motion-видеонаблюдение (регистрацию).

Comment: Похоже, что отключается сетевая карта при бездействии. Сам сервер на линуксе? Пинги тоже прекращают идти? А из сервера можно обратиться на внешние адреса?

Comment: PING 192.168.0.101 (192.168.0.101) 56(84) bytes of data.

Comment: да на линукс, плата находится во внутренней сети не во внешке. я профан в линукс по этому заранее извиняюсь если что не так.

Comment: Может перегрев? Поставить радиатор?

Comment: Перегрев скорее всего не причем, при перегреве происходит троттлинг процессора, больше похоже на сон... использовал на orange pi pc - raspbian все работало отлично) но радиатор я бы все ровно посоветовал поставить ибо orange греется не слабо...